# How do I filter file type for image in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, photo

How do I filter image type in this code ? I want to allow only file type with `jpg, jpeg and png only`?

I did tried with this code but is not working

```
$(".doc").click(function()  {$("#doc_attach").click();});
        $("#doc_attach").change(function()
        {
            let width  = 0;
            let height = 0;
            let photo  = $(this).prop("files")[0];

            if(photo.type == 'image/jpg' || photo.type == 'image/png' || photo.type == 'image/jpeg' ){
                let index;
                index = doc_temp.push({"file": photo}) - 1;
                   ....
                }
                else if( photo.type == 'application/pdf'){
                    let index;
                    index = doc_temp.push({"file": photo}) - 1;  
                }
                else{
                    Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Oops...',
                    text: 'Sorry only file type with jpg and pdf are allowed!',
                    
                    })
                }

        });
```

I tried to upload image with `png` but it was wrong and `oops` popup showed up. How do I filter it correctly ?

Comment: so, what is the value of `photo.type` in your code?

Answer (score 3):

you can also achieve this with the 'accept' attribute for html inputs. Like this:

```
<input type="file" name="myImage" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg" />
```

Comment: if you want to use javascript for this, you have to check the extension of the filename. there is no 'photo.type' property, so you have to check if the extensions are valid. See here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-type-validation-while-uploading-it-using-javascript/